# creating intents and activities across classes

Tags: android, android-intent

I hope this is the appropriate title for this question.  Right now I have two classes.  A main class and a ApplicationOperations class.  Initially I had a method uninstallapplication and listall installed applications which worked fine in my main class.  Now as I move them to another class (in order to expand) they do not work.  I do not know anything about intents as I am still a newbie so any help would be great!

I am getting an error on

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); <--method undefined???
      and
StartActivity <---method undefined.
```

Here is the Code.  Please let me know if you need anything else:

MAIN FILE:

```
package com.IPR2.viewlog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Main extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FileOperations fileOperations = new FileOperations();
        ApplicationOperations applicationOperations = new ApplicationOperations();
        Testing testing = new Testing();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);



    }



}
```

---

```
ApplicationOperations.java

package com.IPR2.viewlog;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class ApplicationOperations {

    FileOperations fileOperations = new FileOperations();

    public void UninstallApplication(String packageName)
{
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+packageName);
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
    startActivity(uninstallIntent);
}

    public void ListAllInstalledApplications()
{       
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); 
    //get a list of installed apps. 
            List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm 
                    .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA); 
            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 
            { 
                fileOperations.AppendFile("Installed package :" + 
                        packageInfo.packageName + "\n", "Installed_packages.txt");
//              tv.append("Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName + "\n");  
            }
} 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your code

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
```

Was inside the Class inherited from Activity class (class Main), it worked because in fact getPackageManager() is Context.getPackageManager. Activity extends Context class, hence everything is okay.
But you moved this code into new class which doesn't extend anything related to Context. Hence you have a compile error. 
You should pass somehow a context into your new class (ApplicationOperations) and use it

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager()
```

Comment: Ahhh! How would I do that? Could you show me?

I have public void ListAllInstalledApplications(Context mContext) but I dont know where to get the mContext?

Comment: it depends on how are u going to use your ApplicationOperations class. I do not see an architecture of the application you are building so I do not know where the methods of the class will be executed from.
If you make these methods static and decide to call from your activity class, then you can pass the context as additional parameter, e.g. if you put this code into your Main class:

    ApplicationOperations.ListAllInstalledApplications(getApplicationContext())

this will work, but you will need to make ListAllInstalledApplications() a static

Answer (score 2):

getPackageManager() need Context.

You can add a Context or Main member in ApplicationOperations class and add a init method to pass Main to it.

```
private Main context;
public ApplicationOperations(Main activity) {
    this.context = activity;
}
```

Then use it when needed

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
```